# Coudnot Install Gradle distribution - eclipse- Liferay

Tags: eclipse, gradle, liferay, liferay-7, gradle-eclipse

[Error shows when I took a new Liferay module project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8ilt.jpg)

I am using eclipse with liferay plugin. when I take a new liferay module project it shows above error    (**Synchronize Gradle builds with workspace failed due to an error connecting to the Gradle build.
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip'.**
).
Is it related to any certificate issue
?. How can I resolve it. Please share your knowledge on this, Thanks.

Comment: u can check this 
https://web.liferay.com/en/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/108220450

Answer (score 1):

JDK8 is must for Liferay 7 / DXP. Make sure the JAVA_HOME is pointing to JDK and not JRE. My `gradle.properties` initializes JDK like `org.gradle.java.home=c:/java/jdk8` .
Howeve, I feel the issue is more inclined to proxy. Please check the proxy restriction on your network. If you can take the machine to open network, I bet you won't find the issue, given everything else in your eclipse is set properly of is defaulted.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime Eclipse is unable to download the file due to size of file, or internet connection lose while downloading the file.

you can download the file from http://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and then paste it into your .gradle/wrapper/dist folder.

Then try to import the project again. It solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you so much it resolved my issue. 
I created dist folder and then added that download gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your JDK8.

It's described in the documentation:

[CERTIFICATION ISSUES IN LIFERAY WORKSPACE](https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/configuring-a-liferay-workspace#certification-issues-in-liferay-workspace)